# Dielectric constant and electronic band structure

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics

Is there any relation between dielectric constant and band gap of a material?

Comment: Both being hardly dependent from the wave function of the electron cloud, I think the answer is obviously yes - hopefully somebody with a deeper knowledge will be able to give a more detailed answer, instead of closing your question as "too broad" or "unclear". Anyways you could heighten your chances, by specifying your question a little bit more, by giving more details.

Comment: (@peterh - I think you mean 'strongly', not 'hardly' there). In general, a detailed answer would be really really long (book length, indeed). But, one can see that materials with no band gap (i.e. metals) have a different dielectric constant (say in the visible) from, say, silicon. Beyond that, though, even in the fairly simple Lorentz picture, one needs to look at the optical properties across the full spectrum to find all the needed 'oscillators' that interact with the EM waves.

Comment: In a first analysis it seams they are not closely related. The band gap is related to the [delocalized electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delocalized_electron) in the material whereas the dielectric constant is related to the behavior of the electrons in each single molecule. The dielectric constant is defined from the electric susceptibility, $\kappa=1+\chi$, and the latter is actually a measure of the [polarizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizability) of the medium which regards only to the electronic cloud.